# C# how to combine two queries and display data in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ms-access, oledb

I want to combine two queries and make it one. Both queries connect from `Table1`.

**1.** Query collect data from table1 for Processor.

**2.** Query collect data from table1 for Process.

**3.** Query collect data from table1 as per from date and to date.

I want to create only one new query for above three query.

I am using **OLEDB** connection to connect MS-Database to Datagridview. Dates format are as `"MM-DD-YYYY"` in database and code.

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data as text table, not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all queries you intend to run on the same table return the same exact columns as results, you can use the SQL clause `UNION` to combine all in one single result table then it is easy to show that query result in a DataGrid on the User Interface.

for example, from here ( but you can search many more examples if this one is too generic )

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/union.php

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
UNION
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```